# Create a company and user in one, what's the standard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know a lot of startups and tech companies essentially allow you to register, and you end up registering a company and your user.

An example would be basecamp for example. I'd like to achieve the same thing, however I'm not quite certain on how they do it, and what the best way to do it is.

My thought is to have a user and company model, where on registration you register a company, and it accepts nested attributes for user. As in my head at least the relation is:

```
 User belongs_to :company
 Company has_many :users
```

and the registration is a Company#new with a company.user.build.

However for some reason this does feel a bit strange, as to me it would make more sense that you register a user, and create the company it belongs to.

I just want to lay the foundation right, so I don't start building anything massive on top of a system that isn't good.

**More info:**
The purpose is to make the person that registers itself and the company an admin, and only allow new users to be a part of a company by being invited by an admin. Everything that goes on within the project is company based only for those within the company. You can also group users that belongs to the company, and create segments or say departments of the company. Beside that the company has no function other that being the connector between all the users that belong to the same company.

Comment: Unless you plan to tie `Company` entities to functionality apart from merely an attribute of a `User` entity, I think you are overthinking this.  In any case you haven't provided enough context to expect good advice either for programming or database design.

Comment: @hardmath I'll update with some more elaboration